# Installing from source a package that has already been installed by the package manager

Tags: install-from-source

I've installed the newest Boost library from source (for c++ needs), but still have an older version installed by the package manager. I've put the newest version in a 'weird' location, not a preserved one.

Now, when I launch my test program with `-I/path/to/include` and `-L/path/to/lib` options I receive errors.

So, my question is: what should I do now to be able to work with both versions?
Will adding that 'weird' location to `PATH` or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable or to `/etc/ld.so.conf` file cause any version conflict?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supply LD_LIBRARY_PATH on launch.

Or on compilation:

```
-Wl,-rpath=/usr/weird/lib
```

See what libraries will be used by the executable:

```
ldd myprogram
```

Comment: The way I made it compile and run: clang++ -I/path/to/include main.cpp -o test -L/path/to/lib  -Wl,-rpath/=path/to/lib -lboost_somelibrary  and then ./test            That's enough. Thanks a lot!